# What does the POST data of HackBar (Firefox add-on) do?

Tags: http, burp-suite, web, header

What does the POST DATA Feature of Hackbar (Addon of Firefox )do ?

If I am checking for XML XXE vulnerability i use it .But what does it do by POSTing some data ?

If I want to repeat the same thing using Burp Suite ,how do I do this ?

[image: Screenshot of Firefox with the Hackbar Addon showing. the "Post Data" Field is circled in]

Comment: Please embed external images.

Comment: how to do that ,sir ?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware that this requires 10 rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IT is used to send a POST request to the Website.

When you enable the checkbox saying "Enable Post Data", the request method will be changed from GET to POST.

Now if you add any data in the "Post data" field ,it will be sent in the body as POST data.
HTTP METHODS CAN BE CHANGED LIKE

```
GET 
POST 
CONNECT
DELETE
PUT ,etc
```

BURP CAN BE used to do the same just get a GET request chagne the type of request from GET TO POST and enter any data if you want to ,that will be sent as POST Data.

Answer (score 2):

It does exactly what it says, it sends a POST request.

If you check "Enable Post Data", the [request method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) will be changed from GET to POST. All data that you enter in the "Post data" field will be send in the body as POST data. The resulting HTTP request will look like this:

```
POST /?foo=bar HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Connection: close

test1=test&test2=test
```

Compare this with a GET request:

```
GET /?foo=bar HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Connection: close
```

You can see that the HTTP method is different, and that a GET method will not send a body.

In Burp, you can either just capture an existing POST request and change it on the fly or send it to the repeater, or you can use "right-click -> Change Request Method" on an existing GET request (or just build the whole request from scratch) to send a POST request.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to POST something to a web server?  I see POST commands in my web server's log files and I know it's being done from hacked systems or from rent-a-server systems (or it's being done from China, Ukraine, etc).  A properly configured website will reject POST commands.